# Make library chunks share the same react context with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, shared-libraries, react-context

I have two projects, one is a react app, the other is a library used by that react app.

The library is bundled with webpack and output three chunks, one called contexts, one called hooks, and one called components

In contexts can be found "myContext" react context (`myLib/src/contexts/myContext.js`)

In hooks can be found "useMyContext" react hook (`myLib/src/hooks/useMyContext.js`)

And in components can be found "MyProvider" component (`myLib/src/components/MyProvider.jsx`)

MyProvider component renders the myContext.Provider, giving it as value the output of the useMyContext.

Now in my react app, I render a component "MyComponent" wrapped with the "MyProvider" imported from my library.

"MyComponent" consumes the myContext imported from my library, and renders its value.

I would expect "MyComponent" to renders the value returned by the "useMyContext" hook, as it is implemented into "MyProvider"

However, "MyComponent" renders the initial value defined in myContext.

Note that if I export myContext and MyProvider in a same chunk, then it's working as expected, but I can't go for that solution in my real use case.

This makes me think that the myContext exported from the contexts chunk is not the same as the myContext used into MyProvider.

I made React a peerDependency in my package.json, to be sure the library relies on the React version from the app, and I made it an externals in Webpack config for the same reason.

What I tried so far was to use the Webpack feature "dependOn", in order to share react across the several chunks. But when I try that, the app raises error "`__webpack_require__ is not a function`" at runtime.

You can find the repository here https://github.com/c0ll1d3r/ReactContextLibraryIssue

Am I on the right track using dependOn ? If yes, would you know why I got that error ? Else what would be correct solution ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it works, actually as I mentioned, exporting everything from the same chunk was working (but not affordable in my project).

From that observation I made the conclusion the issue was that somehow two instances of "myContext" were created when imported from (or used in) two different chunks.

MyProvider was importing the context like this : `import myContext from '../../myContext`

And my app was importing the context like this : `import { myContext } from 'myLib/contexts'`

So I isolated my context in its own library, in order to be able to import it in a consistent way no matter what

Now, MyProvider and my app are importing this context the same way : `import { myContext }` from 'mycontextlib'

Making sure they are working on the same instance, and the value is well propagated